# What is the purpose of @Valid annotated at the class level?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

I'm reviewing some code that someone else wrote and noticed the class is annotated with `@Valid` (`javax.validation.Valid`).  I understand that `@Valid` marks that an object (a property, method parameter or method return type) should be validated during validation cascading. The annotation is allowed on the class. But what purpose does it serve at that level?

I removed the annotation from the class I was reviewing and have not noticed any impact. I've looked online for other code examples with `@Valid` but all examples have it applied at the property, method parameter or method return type.

Here's the code that I'm reviewing:

```
@Valid // Is this needed?
@DateRange(message="invalidStartDate") // a @Constraint validator
public class Surplus {

   @NotNull(message="surplus.startDate.notNull")
   private Date startDate;

  @NotNull(message="surplus.endDate.notNull")
  private Date endDate;
}
```

Comment: That is not the javax.validation.Valid annotation. If it was, your code wouldn't compile because the annotation can't be set on a class: https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Valid.html. So you need to find the actual fully qualified name of this annotation, and read its javadoc.

Comment: That's odd because the code does compile and in the import statements, it indicates `javax.validation.Valid`. I see `@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })` for the annotation usage. Is `TYPE_USE` allowing for this annotation at the class level?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It does indeed compile (I tested it on a Kotlin class first, and it didn't, but it does compile on a Java class, for a reason that I can't understand)